# Eating before leaning on Esther

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Did Haman eat at the party before Ahashveirosh caught him "leaning" on Esther?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6417/eat-before-laining-esther?

Comment: This makes a decent real question, IMHO.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently not.

*Haman*, as we know from various *midrashim*, was quite learned. Doubtless he knew [the *Rambam*](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=113) that says that בימות החמה... ואוכל את החומץ, during the summer months one should eat vinegar. Since *Ester*'s party was right at the beginning of the summer months, on *Pesach*, *Haman* was preparing vinegary food — pickles, in fact — right there at the party. When *Achashverosh* walked back into the party after his trip to the garden, he saw what *Haman* was up to, preparing vinegar for pickling. Thinking *Haman* was planning to pickle *Ester*, [*Achashverosh* said](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%96_%D7%97), "הֲגַם לִכְבּוֹשׁ אֶת הַמַּלְכָּה עִמִּי בַּבָּיִת, do you also plan to pickle the queen with me at home?" and had him killed.

In fact, though, *Haman* had been planning to pickle only vegetables, and what better to pickle than cucumbers? But [the *Rambam*](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=111) also says, "ומיני מלפפונות אוכל אותם האדם בתחלה קודם אכילה, one should eat cucumbers before the rest of the meal" — so we see *Haman* hadn't started eating yet.

Answer (score 3):

Well he was chewing Gam as the Posuk says "Ha**gam**" Lichbosh Es HaMalka Imi BaBayis

Comment: That depends if you hold like Rav Abadi (and lihavdil bein hayim lihayim, Rav Ruderman ZT"L) that gum is not derech achila or like almost everyone else that it is.